# unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Firefox version 36.0.1 and Selenium-Webdriver gem version 2.45.0.
I am able to create Firefox instance but not able to proceed for further operations using script
Getting unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds  (127.0.0.1:7055) error.

Can some one help me ?

Comment: I believe this just comes down to your firefox version being too up to date. We use v33 and have no problems

Comment: "gem update" - this command update all gems, and it was helped me

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. After downgrading to firefox v33 everything worked fine again.

You can find the older versions [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/)

Comment: I downgraded to Firefox V33 (33.0) and am still having this problem.  I just added the `selenium-webdriver` (2.45.0) gem so my problem may be even more basic...  I am using `capybara` (2.4.0) and `database_cleaner` (1.4.1) as well (versions from bundle show).  Any ideas?

Comment: I am using capybara 2.4. Try updating that.

Comment: Thanks Ryan but see my comment above - I am using capybara 2.4.0.  I removed versions in my gemfile for capybara and selenium-webdriver to make sure I have the latest.  Is there some basic Rails config needed for selenium to "find" the Firefox browser on my laptop?  I should mention I am using Cloud9.  Feeling like I am missing something pretty basic...

Comment: Sorry I meant to type `2.4.4`

Comment: after upgrading to El Capitan I had this problem.  Uninstalling Firefox, then installing firefox v33 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox ver. 43.0, capybara ver. 2.5.0, and selenium-webdriver ver. 2.48.1 pack works for me just fine (rails 4.2.3, ruby 2.2.0).

I just had to run bundle update on the two gems:

```
 bundle update capybara
 bundle update selenium-webdriver
```

Comment: I update this and was needed to downgrade the firefox version [33.0.1](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/33.0.1/)

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience, using Selenium-Webdriver 2.45.0 and Firefox v 35.0 will work. If you have a newer version of Firefox installed, it must be removed first. If you're running on MacOS, you will likely have to disable auto-updates within Firefox before you can rollback to v 35.0 (they're enabled by default, and begin immediately when you open Firefox...).

Capybara/Cucumber version shouldn't matter as long as everything else is set correctly (it's just loading a driver anyway).

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

Btw, don't ever use 'bundle update' or 'gem update' arbitrarily. That's like saying "give me the newest versions of all gems from all available sources" without knowing the effects beforehand. It can be a Pandora's Box of trouble if you aren't careful, especially 'bundle update'.